# Header Navbar Bootstrap que ocupe toda la pantalla cuando se despliegue el botón "Hamburguesa"

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3, angular6, navbar

Para hacer mi header he cogido el código de la página Bootstrap Navbar (External content). Quiero que cuando se despliegue el menú del botón "hamburguesa" me ocupe toda la pantalla. Actualmente he hecho varias modificaciones, pero sin conseguir el objetivo de que me ocupe todo. Dejo por aquí mi HTML Y CSS

Header HTML

```
<header>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <img src="assets/img/6.png" id="logo" alt="">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/inicio']">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/curiosidades']">Curiosidades</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/blog']">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/contacto']">Contacto</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

</header>
```

Aquí el CSS

```
header{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

header ul{
  display: block;
  width: 25%;
  height: inherit;
  margin: 0px auto;


}
header ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}

header ul li a{
  color: white;
}

header ul li a:hover{
  color: yellow;

}

#logo{
  width: 6%;
  margin-left: 47.3%;
}
```

Muchas gracias a todos.

Saludos

Comment: Aplicaste la propiedad `height:100vh;` al navbar colapsable?

Comment: si, y no funciona

Comment: Cómo la aplicaste? Muéstranos esa parte del código.

Comment: lo apliqué en el CSS, pero lo eliminé. El código que he subido es lo que tengo actualmente. Igual no lo introduje bien

Comment: Que versión de Bootstrap usas? Descargaste la librería y estás modificando el archivo CSS, o utilizas CDN y aplicas el estilo (<style>...</style>) dentro del html? Es que la verdad la respuesta sencilla es esa, aplicar `height: 100vh;` a la clase `navbar-collapse`

Comment: uso la última versión de Bootstrap y la librería me la instalé a través de NPM

Comment: Lo he puesto así en el CSS. .navbar-collapse{
  height: 100vh;
}

Comment: Vale, ya me lo ha cogido. Muchas gracias por la ayuda @JheymanMejia